# Banned for "Looks OK" on duplicate answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers, review-suspension

Two reviewers and I determined that an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744527/how-can-i-upgrade-my-sql-server-ce-3-5-sdf-database-to-sql-server-ce-4-0) Looks OK. I was banned (I assume the other reviewers were too) from reviewing for 2 days because the answer was not ok. The nature of the incorrect review is that the answer was just a copy-paste of another answer to the same question.

See the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8782787) - this is what I saw when initially reviewing the answer. Looks OK, right? The answer itself is fine but there's an older exact duplicate answer *you would need to navigate to the original question's page to see*. Is this considered part of the audit process? To inspect other answers for duplicates? Seems clunky and not-working-as-intended. If I was supposed to consider the original answer, then it should have been presented to me as part of the review process, right?

Well, I'm snakebitten, and will not be as eager to perform review tasks. And when I do I'll be seeking additional information whenever possible because the system failed me. My ban was already lifted, but I just want to raise this issue and see if there is a better way to present information to reviewers.

Comment: Did you look at the comments? And the last sentence of the answer?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? I can't see anything :(

Comment: @Zizouz212: it's a ~20 line answer, with "This was simple and straight to the point as well as improve productivity. Thanks for sharing it work!!!" as a last sentence. And a comment that says: "seems like you just copy-pasted zviad's answer... or maybe you wanted to comment on his answer that it did work?"

Comment: @Zizouz212 http://i.stack.imgur.com/vLD5n.png

Answer (score 7):

There's two issues with your review:

1. There was a comment describing plagiarism.

   <strike>Nearly the entire contents of an answer was a copy/paste of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15179995/4293417) answer, on the same page. That should've given you a warning sign.</strike> That comment came after your review, so I'll give you a little bit of slack.
2. It's like a 'Thank You' comment:

   > This was simple and to the point as well as improve productivity! Thanks for sharing it work!!!

   That's definitely not an answer, and it's the kind of stuff that should be flagged as 'Not An Answer', or even 'Very Low Quality'. This should've been caught straight away.

---

Regardless, reflect on the action, and seek to improve yourself in the future :)

Comment: consider adding: "Yes, there were two others failing that audit (and also three who upvoted), which just means it was a *good* audit."

Comment: @Deduplicator Good point :)

Comment: @Deduplicator Correct me if I'm wrong, but if it was an audit, there would only be one name on the review, correct? And it would say not that the review was completed, but instead that the audit was passed or failed.

Comment: @Kendra Actually, looking at that again, this looks like a manual suspension. This doesn't look like an audit

Comment: @Zizouz212 That's what I was getting at. :)

Comment: @Kendra: Yes...

Comment: At any rate, point 2 still stands.

Answer (score 1):

In this case *Looks OK* was going to be wrong, whether or not the answer was copy and pasted from another. The very minimum was *Requires Editing* for the horrible last line "Thanks for sharing it work!"

Personally I would have chosen that option then gone to the question to edit that sentence (or just remove it completely for making no sense) where I would have found the duplicate answer. I guess it wasn't the easiest to spot, but reviewers are supposed to review the entire post, not just 99% of it. I would have done the same if a simple "Thank you" was placed at the end too!

Comment: Editing happens within LQP, so that wouldn't help spot the other answer.

Comment: @NathanTuggy You can still click through to the question from the review page by clicking on the title, and flag from there if required.

Comment: Sure, but that requires feeling suspicious. (I use a userscript that pulls in other answers to the review page, but same thing.)